# Jenkins: Unknown stage section "timeout" when I added a timeout section in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Now I want to add a timeout input in jenkins pipeline, if 60 seconds the user not input the choose, it will jump the next steps and mark build success. If the user choose ''**YES**, the next steps will be executed. this is my code:

```
stage('push-image-uat') {

            timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                 input {
                     message "Publish to uat environment?"
                     ok "Yes, we should."
                     submitter "admin,anthony"
                     parameters {
                         string(name: 'CHOOSE', defaultValue: 'NO', description: 'Should I publish to uat?')
                     }
                 }
            }

            when {
                expression {
                    ${params.CHOOSE} == 'YES'
                }
            }

            steps{
                script {
                    publishToUATEnvironment = true
                }
                sh "echo \"push image uat\""
                echo "Hello, ${CHOOSE}, nice to meet you."
            }
        }
```

but when I run this script in jenkins, it thows this error:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 57: Unknown stage section "timeout". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 57, column 9.
           stage('push-image-uat') {
           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

what should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
stage('push-image-uat') {
      steps {

        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
             input {
                 message "Publish to uat environment?"
                 ok "Yes, we should."
                 submitter "admin,anthony"
                 parameters {
                     string(name: 'CHOOSE', defaultValue: 'NO', description: 'Should I publish to uat?')
                 }
             }
          }
        }
     }
```

The `timeout block` must be within `steps block`

and for Best practices always go with this flow for Declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage(""){
      steps {
        script {
        
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `try catch or timeout etc.` blocks within script block